# Can the ability, return target permeant to hand, be activated on the creature that uses the ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Using a specific example, [Ancestral Statue](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ancestral%20Statue).

I have played many different card games and they all have different rules regarding this ability. If I had no other permanents would Ancestral Statue return itself?

Comment: Note that you can choose Ancestral Statue to target itself even if you do have other non-land permanents.

Comment: Also note that Ancestral Statue doesn't target.

Comment: Look at the link you posted. Under "Rulings" it says exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

Since Ancestral Statue doesn't say "Return **another** nonland permanent, it is possible it will return it self if it is the only permanent you control when it enters the battlefield under your control.

"Another" is an important word; [Invasive Species](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Invasive%20Species) won't return itself.

Answer (score 1):

yes it can and in the case where it is the only non-land permanent, since it doesn't say you 'may' return, it actually forces you to return it to your hand. This is not an option, the ability is forced and therefore must be played.